Rewrite all request to webpage in the root in IIS 10 using URL Rewrite
I have a web server that is being used to display a maintenance page that is located in IIS Default Web Site, which loads a webpage in the root from any URL that points to the IP address.  There are a few different URL's going here.
I need a rewrite or redirect so if there is more in the URL after the domain (ex. http://a.domain.com/1 or /1/2/...) it will still load the main page in the root of the Default Web Site.
My current rule sort of works in loading the webpage for any URL enter, but it will not load the graphic as I think it is stuck in the rewrite rule, only the text is displayed, but not the background image.  If I disable the rule, then the page will load with the graphic.
URL Rewrite Info:
`    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to Root Webpage" enabled="true">
        <match url="^(?!\/$).*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" appendQueryString="true" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>`

Webpage:
`    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Maintenance Mode</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-image: url("Down-Background.png");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .container {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            padding: 40px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            max-width: 600px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    
        h1 {
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .footer {
            font-size: 1rem;
            color: #ccc;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>We’re busy pushing improvements to give you a flawless user experience</h1>
        <p>We’ll be back soon!</p>
        <div class="footer">Thank you for your patience.</div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>`


Try adding the following conditional and you should be able to fix the problem， something like this:
 <rule name="Rewrite to Root Webpage" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^(?!\/$).*" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>

Filter requests by determining whether they are file or directory paths to prevent them from triggering this rule.

Thank you for the help.  So we are almost there as this works on the root (http://a.domain.com/) and the 1st subfolder (http://a.domain.com/1).  Once I go another subfolder deep the background image goes away (http://a.domain.com/1/2).
Do you have any suggestions to make the work for multiple subfolders deep?

If the resource you tried to access in some specific subfolder, you can try add this condition: <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="SubfolderName/(.*)" negate="true" /> based on the answer above, it should work for you.
